# How can I instruct nginx to interpret an individual file as php

Tags: nginx, php, web-server

A legacy application relies on the following .htaccess rule for an individual file

```
<Files MyFile.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

The new machine has nginx and php-fpm installed with the following config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another location block for your html file:

```
location = /path/to/MyFile.html {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, as the PHP-FPM default configuration allows only `.php` scripts to be executed. Solution using `rewrite` is cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `MyFile.html` to `MyFile.php`, and add the following to configuration to the `server` level:

```
rewrite ^/path/to/MyFile\.html$ /path/to/MyFile.php last;
```

This makes an internal redirect in nginx that matches the `.html` version and redirects to the PHP script for execution. The PHP processing block in your question then processes the request.